# PayPal Credit or No Credit

Tags: paypal

I  wanted to make sure not to bounce checks at end of Month (Christmas time) I activated my PayPal Credit first online, then the option that said IN STORE PURCHASE. I proceeded to use, however I noted an overdrawn, called PayPal, I was told my online credit purchase was not taken by the merchant, so they just took it from my account at the bank? Next, every single In Store Purchase was taken from my Bank not Credit.

I called PayPal about the online rejection and was told not to worry as the bank was holding and if there was a problem they would resolve and said they tagged my account. Next I start seeing my In Store purchase bounce. I call PayPal, they tell me my Card CAN NOT be used for In Store? I point out I signed up on the website there is a place to authorize funding. They repeatedly tell it's not true, it is not there??? I am LOOKING at it on my screen, in my account.

I get transferred, the guy is very nice and says YES it IS on the Website, it should be removed because it is confusing and no PayPal does not offer that service???? WTF I now have $200 in overdraft, PayPal says Sorry, we will Issue a letter to you to the bank. The letter says how "I" made a mistake, not PayPal I have to just hope the bank will reverse the charges??

How can PayPal offer this Credit In Writing where I specified funding from PayPal Credit, then not honor their signed agreement? Even after (finally) getting PayPal employee to say yes it is there on our website. I downloaded the page, so I have a hard copy.

Comment: This sounds like it has been really frustrating, but it sounds like it was an issue between you and PayPal, which you've talked through with them. Can you help us understand what your actual question is for us?

Comment: Sure, my question is I'm out over $200 -- I think if anyone used a Credit Card then found out that the Card Company just drafted your money from the bank and left you with a string of overdraft charges, you might have a complaint? It is between me and Paypal, thought someone here would know more, Paypla already told me to just suck it up. I assume then that's my answer?

Comment: Ug- that is unfortunate. But note you aren't actually "out" the $200 since you were going to have to pay it back anyway (minus the fees)- so do you have enough to pay it now? If yes, you might have some luck depositing enough to cover the purchases and explaining it to your bank and getting the fees reversed. Perhaps bringing the funds with you to the bank and discussing with a manger in person at the bank would help. If you don't have the money now, unfortunately you may want to consider returning the items, if possible.

Comment: Actually I am out. After my standard Direct Deposit on 1/1/20 the Bank will keep the Overdraft fees. I went to the Bank, with the letter from PayPal and the Bank very Politely told me "No" the will not reverse the now 5 over draft fees as the honored all payments.